# How can I modify Angular component to get information from backend?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, firebase

I have ts file and I would like to create POST method inside component. I try in the way shown below unfortunately without positive results.

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/", JSON.stringify({ body: 'String' }), {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

**UPDATE**

I have a little modified my backend logic and I realized that I don't need to send body in `POST` method. I can send my data in URL parameter. I would like to send GET request and assign received data to object `object.sth` which needs object of `Isth[]` type. At this moment my code looks in the way shown below. However `console.log("data: "+object.sth);` after assignment returns `data: undefined`.

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/path?sth=exampleurl", headers).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
object.sth = this.data;
```

Comment: What is being returned from the post? I expected json, but the status indicates it might be somethiing else? You indicate that in your headers.

Comment: @bgraham I have updated my question. Sorry for changes but I realized that I can do it in another way. Do you know how can I solve my problem now?  Thank your for patience!

Comment: No problem, hope I can help. The typescript/angular call looks right. You said the api returns correctly from postman? Is your "http" from you constructor. Is it an "Http" or an "HttpClient". One thing you can try that might help is to remove the .map(res=>res.json()). This way you will get the entire response object including the status code ect and not just the payload. You can try logging that to the console and see if your getting anything back at all. Let me know and I'll try to help more.

Comment: @bgraham Yes, backend works properly with Postman and sends data response in JSON.

Comment: @bgraham When I remove `.map(res=>res.json())` I get `Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'IMytype[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Response'.`

Comment: OK, typescript error. You must have defined the return type of the method as IMyType[], try changing that to any. The part about missing 'Response' might require you to add import { Response } from '@angular/http'; Thats also typescript checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154080/discussion-between-john-smith-and-bgraham).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(YOURSTRING), {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

It should work for request. (Ur first question)

Comment: I tried this `this.http.post("http://localhost:8000", JSON.stringify("My String"), {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})` before but I got error `Property 'http' does not exist on type 'PersonComponent'`

Comment: constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


add this string to ur component
you shoud inject ur http client via constructor

Comment: `Cannot find name 'HttpClient'
`

Comment: @JohnSmith Add `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to update the answer with more complete syntax. Hopefully that can get     you something running without an error.

```
import { Http }       from '@angular/http';
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    private headers: Headers;
    private options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-        urlencoded' });
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.doPost().subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    doPost() {
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/sth", this.options).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Original:
I think what you're missing is the subscribe. Observables won't execute unless you subscribe to them.

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/", JSON.stringify({ body: 'String' }), {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
```

Just for the record, it is usually better to put your http calls in a service, not inside the component.

Comment: In this case I also get `Property 'http' does not exist on type 'PersonComponent'`. I have tried `import {Http} from '@angular/http';` but still the same error.

Comment: gotcha. You'll need to inject it in your constructor of your component. so constructor(private http: Http) { }. Then angular will inject the service for you.

Comment: With `private http: Http` in constructor I get ```Argument of type '{ headers: { 'Content-Type': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type '{ 'Content-Type': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Content-Type'' does not exist in type 'Headers'.)```

Comment: maybe put this ahead of it: let myHeaders = new Headers(); 
  myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders }); Then pass in myHeaders instead of the '{ headers: { 'Content-Type': string; }; }'

Comment: Unfortunately I still have errors. I have added my code in updated question. Content of error - `Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
      Property 'keys' is missing in type 'Headers'.)`

Answer (score 0):

in top of ur component

```
import { Headers, Http } from "@angular/http";
```

ur component:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {} 

yourRequest() {
   let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })

  this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(YOURSTRING), headers).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
}
```